# Make XAMPP program directory writeable?

Tags: macos, mac, security, permissions, xampp

I'd like to be able to write to the XAMPP directory so that I can run PHP scripts from there rather than my "Sites" user folder.

How can I do that? I'm using 1.7.3.

Currently, if I try to write (copy or save files to) to the XAMPP Application directory, I get a file permissions error. I have a similar issue with the wordpress code editor. (It says to make the file "writeable".)

Comment: Can you describe the problem more clear please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions problem. You can set permissions for the XAMPP folder by right clicking on it and click on Get Info. From there expand Sharing and Permissions at the bottom if it already isn't. Depending on where the folder is you may need to click the lock icon at the bottom right to allow you to make changes. Then you will have access to change the permissions.

If your user account is not in there already, click the little + icon in the lower left and add your user account in. Finally, next to your account name in the Privilege column select Read and Write. You should now be able to write files into this folder, and this process is also the same for adding write permissions to files.

Comment: Plus one for the bit about adding my User Account to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the folder you want to write on choose Get Info and at the bottom you can change Sharing & Permissions now they must be read only and you should change them to read and write. good luck...

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative solution which involves making Apache to run under your UNIX user account
[Local XAMPP development and UNIX file permissions](http://blog.mfabrik.com/2010/12/22/local-xampp-development-and-unix-file-permissions/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Mac OS X and XAMPP, let's assume that your folder with your site or API located in folder /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/API. Then you can grant access like this:

```
$ chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/API
```

And now open the page inside the folder:

```
http://localhost/API/index.php
```